# Creating a symbolic link in /bin is not working

Tags: macos, terminal

I've tried three different ways to create a symbolic link to Sublime Text on my Mac and, after restarting terminal each time, it still keeps telling me command not found. I'm using a Mac with Yosemite (OSX Yosemite, 10.10). How can I create a symbolic link so I can open Sublime with the `sub` command?

**One**

```
ln -s 'Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' /bin/sub
```

**Two**

```
ln -s "Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /bin/sub
```

**Three** (no quotes)

```
ln -s Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /bin/sub
```

Comment: does the link actually create something in /bin called sub? try sudo?

Comment: If you use quotes, you do not want the backslash.  If you don't use quotes, the backslash is necessary.  You also need the leading slash on `/Applications/…`, as pointed out in the answer, and you need root privileges to write in `/bin` (hence `sudo`).  The residual question is whether it is sufficient to run the executable like that.  Are you sure you don't want a shell script that does something like `open "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app"` instead as the contents of the file in `/bin`?

Answer (score 16):

You're missing the '/' at the beginning of your app and `sudo` as `/bin` is owned by `root` and you can't actually write to it as a normal user. As you currently have it, it would only work if your present directory was the system root. This assumes of course that the Sublime Text app is in your main Applications folder.

Try this…

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /bin/sub
```

---

One afterthought: It's considered bad practice to change the content of `/bin` and `/usr/bin` because any upcoming OS X upgrade may wipe the content there. `/usr/local/bin` is the usual place to install user-provided binaries in, so

```
[[ -d /usr/local/bin ]] || sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/sub
```

might be the better option.

Or (as you probably never need to run Sublime Text from within a shell script), simply define a bash alias

```
alias sub=/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

which should be added to your bash startup file to make it stick

```
echo "alias sub=/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: You need to use `sudo` and if you are going to quote the pathname then don't use backslashes to escape spaces!

Comment: Don't forget single quotation marks around the path: 
alias subl='/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'
Also better put that into ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party. I encountered the same issue when setting up my Mac and tried a few things. Here is what worked for me.

```
ln -sv "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

For more information, go to this [github repo](https://gist.github.com/adrianorsouza/df4759b0583dcd112da4).

Comment: Aside from the fact that your command will fail, since you didn't use `sudo` and it's required in this case, how is this any different then what's already been offered within mockman's answer? Other then that fact that he choose to use `sub` vs. `subl`, so as to type one less character repeatedly to use it, it's really not from what I can see!

Comment: @user3439894 sudo is not a requirement. **AND** the command above uses `/usr/local/bin` not `/usr/bin` as the commands above. `/usr/local/bin` is the recommend directory for user applications whereas /usr/bin is used for distribution-managed user programs. So, `sub` vs `subl` is **not** the only change, it simply depends on user preference; what they want to write. I apologize if it causes confusion..

Comment: 1. Running your command as is from an admin account, returns **`ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: Permission denied`** 2. I'd suggest you reread mockman"s answer as it absolutely has `/usr/local/bin/` in the second `sudo ln -s` command in his answer!